# What is the encoding for OPT, TTF, EOT, and WOFF?

Tags: encoding, truetype, opentype, woff, eot

What is the encoding for OPT, TTF, EOT, and WOFF? 
I can't seem to find them.

Is there a list of encodings mapped to file types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word “encoding” is typically used with character data. Since the TTF file format is based on bytes, it doesn’t have a “character encoding”. It does have some fields with character data, but then the question should be “what is the encoding of these fields inside the file?” — the file as a whole doesn’t have an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

They are binary files.

From [here](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=IWS-Chapter08), for example...

> A TrueType font is a binary file containing a number of tables.